# Song with a theme of "Love me now, but give it time and I'll make you hate me"

Tags: identify-this-song, pop

I'm looking for an apologetic song with a theme of "you're loving me now, but give it time and I’m gonna make you hate me."

It was a female artist and it was popular in early 2015. I can’t remember any specific lyric or the tune. But it was a slower ballad type song and I used to listen to it on a radio station that boasts “80’s, 90’s and now”. I’ve searched the charts from that time and come up blank but it could’ve been an older song that was just getting a lot of air time then. I’ve been searching for days and it’s driving me crazy. Please help.

Comment: Hi Lisa and welcome. You have almost no details of the song except "Female, ballad, 2015"... please try to add more or the question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Amy Winehouse [I'm No Good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-I2s5zRbHg).  The timeframe isn't quite right (2006) but the mood is similar --she's warning her lover about her bad qualities.